# Fields must be specified with a type function error - Keystone

Tags: mongoose, keystonejs

What i want to achieve in KeyStone

1. I have labConfigs table which looks like below. For each item of LabConfigs table i want to store "UserauthLevel" in Domain  table.

   So that's  i want to create "Array of boolean Object " in domain table. 
   Below is code for same.

   ```
       ****************LabConfigs***********************
       var LabConfigs = new keystone.List('LabConfigs');

       LabConfigs.add({
        configName: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
        description: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
        image: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
        type: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
        version: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
       });
       ************************************************
   ```

   Below is my code for Domain table  :-

   ```
       **************************Domain table******

        var Domain = new keystone.List('Domain');
        Domain.add({
         domainName: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
        labConfigs :{type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'LabConfigs',required: false,many: true},
        userauthlevel:[{ type: Types.Boolean}]
        });
       Domain.defaultColumns = 'domainName';
       Domain.register();
   ```

   But after running this throw it give me error :-

   ```
      throw new Error('Fields must be specified with a type function');
       ^
   ```

   To solve this problem i tried following code in domain table

   ```
       Domain.schema.add ({
              userauthlevel :
                         [{
                         type: Types.Text
                        }]
            });
   ```

   but this also not help.

   Any suggestions how to solve this problem i know it might work in mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly specifying an array of booleans for your `userauthlevel` property. Keystone doesn't have a Boolean Array type, but it has `Types.TextArray` which you can use to store multiple possible booleans on a document.

```
userauthlevel: { types: Types.TextArray }
```

Any array you pass to it is considered an array of strings, so you'd have to convert any stored values to their proper true/false value on your own.

Comment: Hi,  As i couldn't see any example of TextArray. Can you point me to correct example of TextArray.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/fields/types/textarray) some documentation from their GitHub repo.

Comment: Any good example that how to insert elements in this TextArray of userauthlevel